# FFMPEG Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to run the following command for my Android app:

```
"ffmpeg -i /full/path.video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i myGif.gif -filter_complex \"[0][1]overlay=0:H-100\" /full/path/videoWithGifOverlay.mp4"
```

but I am getting am getting an error.

Here is the ouput:

```
04-14 18:36:30.386 30508-30508/com.example.android.camera2video I/onProgress(): ***Output #0, mp4, to 'ffmpeg -i /full/path/video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i myGif.gif -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=0:H-100" /full/path/videoWithGifOverlay.mp4':
04-14 18:36:30.386 30508-30508/com.example.android.camera2video I/onProgress(): ***Output file #0 does not contain any stream
04-14 18:36:30.386 30508-30508/com.example.android.camera2video E/onFailure(): ***ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
    configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- 
    --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot 
    --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads 
    --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm 
    --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config 
    --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include 
    -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib 
    -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
    libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
    libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
    libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
    libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
    libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
    libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
    libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
    libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  Output #0, mp4, to 'ffmpeg -i /full/path/video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i myGif.gif -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=0:H-100" /full/path/videoWithGifOverlay.mp4':
  Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I am trying to save a video, after its recorded, with a gif overlay on it.

Comment: It appears that your output file is named `ffmpeg -i /full/path/video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i myGif.gif -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=0:H-100" /full/path/videoWithGifOverlay.mp4` instead of `videoWithGifOverlay.mp4`. Probably the typical, common Android quoting issue.

Answer (score 2):

if you take a look at the FFmpeg android sample, you will see that they are separating every " "(space) , so instead of passing an integrated string command you should do something like this:

```
String[] commands = new String[10];
commands[0] ="-i";
commands[1] = "/full/path.video.mp4";
```

......

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problem. i applied ffmpeg to decode a h264 file:

ffmpeg  -hide_banner -vsync 0  -i .\h264\test_hp_cbr16_20M.h264  -pix_fmt yuv420p -y rec.yuv
[h264 @ 000001ad31d8ae80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, h264, from '.\h264\test_hp_cbr16_20M.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'rec.yuv':
**Output file #0 does not contain any stream**

The reason for "Output file #0 does not contain any stream" - the input file is empty (the filesize is 0)