# FFmpeg error Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm getting an error while cutting a portion of a video using FFmpeg

Following is my code

```
String[] cmd = {"ffmpeg -ss 0 -i "+mPath+" -t 30 -c copy "+ (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/sample.mp4")};
executeCommand(cmd);
```

**Function executeCommand**

```
void executeCommand(String[] cmd) {
    try {
        fFmpeg.execute(cmd, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(VideoFullScreen.this, "finished :" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("Error",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Error**

> ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>
> built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>
> configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>
> libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>
> libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>
> libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>
> libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>
> libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>
> libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>
> libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>
> libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>
> Output #0, mp4, to 'ffmpeg -ss 0 -i /storage/emulated/0/Video/Demo.mp4 -t 30 -c copy /storage/emulated/0/sample.mp4':
>
> Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Comment: Will you post your java code for file creating?? and have you checked your input file?

Comment: @UpendraShah Do we need to create an output file ?
FFmpeg will automatically create one right ?

Comment: Yes we have to create output file too for getting output.

Comment: @UpendraShah Still am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you added read and write external storage permission?

Comment: add -report option to ffmpeg:
Dump full command line and console output to a file named program-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.log in the current directory. This file can be useful for bug reports. It also implies -loglevel verbose. Hopefully from the log you can see where there error is.

Comment: @UpendraShah Yes

Comment: ffmpeg is treating the entire command string as an output filename. You need to debug your Java code. Not a ffmpeg issue.

Comment: Trackback to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421298/ffmpeg-output-file-0-does-not-contain-any-stream) which wound up being the exact same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This is an answer to my own question

My problem was in the command string array i was passing

> This answer is to the people who all are facing the similar kind of issues with `ffmpeg`

**Important things you should follow while using `ffmpeg`**

1. Make sure, you are passing the commands in proper `String Array`

   ```
   String[] cmd = {"-ss", "0", "-i" ,input_video_path, "-t" ,"30", "-c", "copy",output_video_path};
   ```
2. Do not add any `extra space` in arguments and flags you are passing
   {`" -c"` is wrong }
3. Do not pass `ffmpeg` in the cmd array
   {`"ffmpeg" is` wrong }

Hope this will help someone