# Unable to find a suitable output format for "-i ... "

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using writemind's ffmpeg module (running ffmpeg v3.0.2)
http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

But I am getting the follow error when executing the command

> [NULL @ 0xe93aa000] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -i
>   "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.charaku.popsical.tv/cache/video_recording.mp4"
>   -i "/storage/emulated/0/Download/132859_aac-group-2.mp4" -c:v copy  -filter_complex '[1:a] adelay=2500|2500 [delayed]; [0:a] [delayed] amix [out]'  -map 0:v  -map '[out]' 
>   "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.charaku.popsical.tv/cache/mixed_test2.mp4"'
>   -i "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.charaku.popsical.tv/cache/video_recording.mp4"
>   -i "/storage/emulated/0/Download/132859_aac-group-2.mp4" -c:v copy  -filter_complex '[1:a] adelay=2500|2500 [delayed]; [0:a] [delayed] amix [out]'  -map 0:v  -map '[out]' 
>   "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.charaku.popsical.tv/cache/mixed_test2.mp4":
>   Invalid argument

The command is supposed to mix the audio of a video file with the audio of another audio file to produce a new video file.

Answer (score 0):

Able to get pass this error by following the suggestion in this link
[FFmpeg error Output file #0 does not contain any stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365713/ffmpeg-error-output-file-0-does-not-contain-any-stream)

Basically putting each argument in its own array element